# How to add text to the form in smartclient? TS2339: Property 'fields' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: smartclient

SmartClient Version: v12.1p_2021-05-22/LGPL Deployment (built 2021-05-22)

I have just copied code from documentation:
https://smartclient.com/smartclient-latest/isomorphic/system/reference/?id=class..HeaderItem

```
<DynamicForm width="300">
    <fields>
        <field defaultValue="Office Supplies" type="header"/>
        <field title="Item" type="text"/>
    </fields>
</DynamicForm>
```

Getting those errors:

```
 src/page/invoicing/tabs/InvoiceAdHocChargesTabLayout.tsx:57:25 - error TS2339: Property 'fields' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

57                         <fields>
                           ~~~~~~~~

src/page/invoicing/tabs/InvoiceAdHocChargesTabLayout.tsx:58:29 - error TS2339: Property 'field' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

58                             <field defaultValue="Office Supplies" type="header"/>
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/page/invoicing/tabs/InvoiceAdHocChargesTabLayout.tsx:59:29 - error TS2339: Property 'field' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

59                             <field title="Item" type="text"/>
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/page/invoicing/tabs/InvoiceAdHocChargesTabLayout.tsx:60:25 - error TS2339: Property 'fields' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

60                         </fields>
                           ~~~~~~~~~

[12:30:00 PM] Found 8 errors. Watching for file changes.



///<reference path="../ds/InvoiceAdHocChargeDataSource.ts"/>
///<reference path="tabs/InvoiceRecordPriceTab.ts"/>
```

Full file:

```
namespace page.invoicing.tabs {

    import InvoiceAdHocChargeDataSource = page.invoicing.ds.InvoiceAdHocChargeDataSource;


    export class InvoiceAdHocChargesTabLayout implements core.Layout<isc.IVLayout> {

        readonly sc: isc.IVLayout;


        public _listGridRecords: isc.IListGrid<InvoiceAdHocChargeDataSource.Record>


        private _dynamicForm: isc.IDynamicForm<InvoiceAdHocChargeDataSource.Record>;
        private readonly _newFormFields = ["feeCode", "description", "price", "quantity", "vatCode", "remarks"];


        private readonly _events = {

        }

        get events() {
            return utils.Callback.publish(this._events)
        }

        constructor() {
            this.sc =
                <VLayout>
                    <HLayout height={30} membersMargin={5} layoutMargin={0}>
                        <LayoutSpacer/>

                    </HLayout>
                    {this._listGridRecords =
                        <ListGrid dataSource={InvoiceAdHocChargeDataSource.sc()}
                                  useAllDataSourceFields={false}
                                  autoFetchData={false}
                                  selectionType="single"
                                  // editEvent="doubleClick"
                                  showRecordComponents
                                  showRecordComponentsByCell
                                  // createRecordComponent={(record, colNum) => this._createListGridRecordComponent(record, colNum)}
                                  // canEdit={core.AccessControl.instance.has(InvoiceRecordDataSource.get(), c.system.type.Permission.Update)}
                        >
                            <ListGridField name={"feeCode"}/>
                            <ListGridField name={"description"}/>
                            <ListGridField name={"quantity"}/>
                            <ListGridField name={"price"}/>
                            <ListGridField name={"vat"}/>
                        </ListGrid>
                    }

                    <DynamicForm width="300">
                        <fields>
                            <field defaultValue="Office Supplies" type="header"/>
                            <field title="Item" type="text"/>
                        </fields>
                    </DynamicForm>


                    {

                        this._dynamicForm =
                            <DynamicForm dataSource={InvoiceAdHocChargeDataSource.sc()} useAllDataSourceFields={true}>
                                <FormFieldItem name="feeCode"
                                               required={true}
                                />
                                <FormFieldItem name="description"
                                               required={true}
                                />
                                <FormFieldItem name="price"
                                               required={true}
                                />
                                <FormFieldItem name="quantity"
                                               required={true}
                                />
                                <FormFieldItem name="vatCode"
                                               required={true}
                                />
                                <FormFieldItem name="remarks"/>


                            </DynamicForm>
                    }

                </VLayout>
        }

        showNewForm() {
            // todo matyt inicializtuot pagal InvoiceDataTabLayout
            this._dynamicForm.getFields().forEach((item) => {
                if (item.name && this._newFormFields.indexOf(item.name) > -1) {
                    item.show()
                } else {
                    item.hide()
                }
            })
        }


    }
}
```

What is wrong here that code copied from documentation does not work? What I am missing? Where to look at?

Documentation shows .xml example. My file is .tsx. So probably need to change something in that example.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to add text:

```
<HTMLFlow contents={`<span>test</span>`}/>
```